# Grid Render without headers - extjs 4.2.1

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.2

i has create a workspace with sencha tools and generate my project with classic theme.
When i try to show a simple grid, the header and the grid frame aren't successfuly render.

You can check my app: i have one grid at the operations panel in the west and another grid in the message box (south panel)

http://vitornobrega.dyndns-server.com:90/DEV/ExtJS/TradingManager2App/

What i can do in my grids?

Answer (score 0):

Looked at the two grids, one appears to have a header and the other doesn't. I see the header on the south panel, not the west. Upon further inspection (using Ext.getCmp on the grid ID) reveals that the **hideHeaders** config property on that grid is set to true. This would of course make sense why you do not see the headers. Try changing this to false (or remove the setting for true, as it should default to false).